# z-index and position: absolute issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have menu and when user scrolls down, it should have position fixed and z-index to be on top of the page. But in my case, I've set position absolute and z-index but text below menu is shown. How to make menu over this text?

My code is:

```js
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 0) {
            $(".nav-primary").addClass("scrolled");
        }
        else {
            $(".nav-primary").removeClass("scrolled");
        }
    });
```

```css
 #theme-wrapper-inner {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1240px;

}

.scrolled {
    animation: 650ms ease 0s normal none 1 running move-menu-down;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 1240px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="theme-wrapper">
    <div id="theme-wrapper-inner">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12">
                    <div class="site-id mobile-four clearfix">
                         <div class="site-title-wrapper"><h1 class="site-title">My Site</h1></div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          
          <div class="navigation">
                <div class="row" style=" ">
                    <div class="large-12">
                        <nav class="nav-primary" role="navigation">
                            <div id="menu">
                               
                                <ul class="nav-primary">
                                  <li>Home</li>
                                  <li>About us</li>
                                  <li>Contact us</li>
                                </ul>

                                
                            </div>
                        </nav>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The text isn't showing on top of your menu but below it. But because your menu doesn't have a background color.. you see the text trough your menu.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I set  .scrolled { background-color: #fff}